# findoutgoing() got an unexpected keyword argument 'heads'

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am getting this error message when I try to push my changes to a remote Hg repo.

I'm using tortoiseHg 1.1.5 with Hg 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in hg-git

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in hg-git.
When I disable hg-git in my mecurial.ini, the problem solved.